# Open Android app from browser intent with custom campaign parameter

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-intent, intentfilter

I am using `IntentFilter` to open app from browser and check if the app is installed or redirect to the Play Store if it is not.

My problem is, I don't know how to send '`utm_campaign` parameter in second case. Is it possible to send it in Javascript when using intent like this

`(intent://messagecenter/#Intent;____end;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.
https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-on-android-chrome-intents

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to achieve this is `Firebase`. [Firebase's Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) are special links that can open the app if app is installed otherwise can take the user to `PlayStore` page. It is very easy to do and this feature is free as well.

If you don't want to do this, you have to `DeepLink` certain url or format into your app and there you can extract all the campaign tracking information.

In your `target activity` write this code `getIntent().getData().toString()` to get URL address.

However I would suggest to use First Approach as it is very easy and you get many more feature and deep insights about your app with minimal effort.